# Copy and iterate on vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, copy

I try to copy a vector *previousVector* into another vector *currentVector* in C++.

My code is below. 
I want to navigate *currentVector* and based on condition on values, add element in *previousVector*. I'm not sure that is the correct way to do.

```
int ChooseElement(std::vector<Powers>* previousVector) {
    std::vector<Powers> currentVector(*previousVector);
    for(auto iter = currentVector.begin(); iter != currentVector.end(); iter++ ) {
      if(condition on (*iter)) 
        (*previousPowers).push_back(someValue);
    }
    return 0
}

main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    std::vector<myObjectType> listOfElements;
    myObjectType result = myObjectType(1,2);
    listOfElements.push_back(result);
    result = ChooseElements(&listOfElements);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the correct way is `std::copy_if`

Comment: Any reason why you are using a pointer to pass your vector to a function and not a reference?

Comment: If you do not expect to pass `nullptr` you better pass by (const) reference, instead of pointer

Comment: I don't quite understand what your function is supposed to be doing.  You have already copied the vector here: `std::vector<Powers> currentVector(*previousVector);` -- and then you want to add to your original vector more items from essentially the original vector? `(*previousPowers).push_back(someValue);` ??

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie why do you think that `someValue` is from original or new vector?

Comment: @Claudia what's wrong with `push_back()` why you are not sure?

Comment: @Slava I'm not sure that `push_back( )` in original vector is not influenced by the iterator on `currentVector`. I have this doubt because of the kind of copy that I made `std::vector<Powers> currentVector(*previousVector)` .

Comment: If I understand correctly, you copied the whole vector (an expensive operation) just because iterators don't work as well as index for your situation.  **When iterators don't work as well as indexes, just use indexes**

Comment: @Claudia do you copy whole vector because of iterator invalidation?

Comment: @Claudia The copying of the entire vector just to add items to the back of the original vector is unnecessary.  Even if you didn't know any algorithms, the better approach would have been to create a brand new vector of the items you are going to add, and just append it to the existing vector after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to navigate currentVector and based on condition on values, add element in previousVector.

If your intention is to add *the* element that you're iterating, then that is exactly what [std::copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) is for:

```
std::copy_if(currentVector.begin(), currentVector.end(),
             std::back_inserter(previousVector), condition_functor);
```

If you intend to do what your code does, then you don't need `currentVector` at all because it's values don't appear to be used for anything. What your code does is: it adds `someValue` to `previousVector` and does it `n` times where `n` is the number of elements in `previousVector` for which the condition is true. If that's indeed what you intend, then this is a simpler way to do it:

```
void ChooseElement(std::vector<Powers>& v) {
    auto count = std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), condition_functor);
    v.insert(v.end(), count, someValue);
}
```

Comment: OP copies whole vector and then add new elements based on condition, how it is related to `std::copy_if`?

Comment: @Slava it's usually not safe to assume that OP's code does what they want it to do. I answered to how to do what the quoted desire states. If this is not what OP is looking for, then I may have misunderstood their requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your `push_back()` should be fine, as `currentVector` is a deep copy of original vector, so operations on `previousVector` does not affect it at all. But this method is very ineffective, use temporary vector instead:

```
int ChooseElement(std::vector<Powers> &previousVector) {
    std::vector<Powers> tmp;
    for(auto iter = previosVector.begin(); iter != previousVector.end(); iter++ )   {
      if(condition on (*iter)) 
        tmp.push_back(someValue);
    }
    std::move( tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), std::back_inserter( previousVector ) );      
    return 0;
}
```

If you cannot use c++11 replace `std::move()` with:

```
   previosVector.insert( previosVector.end(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end() );
```

Comment: Why is your temporary vector more efficient? It means allocating memory twice, once for the temporary vector, `tmp`, and again to insert into `previousVector`. You should at least use `previousVector.reserve(previousVector.size() + tmp.size())`

Comment: @JonathanWakely it is more efficient than to copy whole `previousVector` and add data to `previousVector` in the loop. I think it is pretty obvious why.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that the inefficiency you refer to is due to the deep copy, as it seems like you are suggesting that "use temporary vector instead" is the solution, but simply not making the copy is the important part of your answer. You could avoid the copy and add directly to `previosVector` without using `tmp` (by iterating using indices not iterators). Also, the OP apparently can use C++11, because the original code uses `auto`.

Comment: The cleanest and most efficient solution might be to use `count_if` first to find out how much to `reserve`, then use `copy_if` together with `back_inserter` to do the work.  That executes the condition twice as many times (might be inefficient) but saves enough other cost to probably be worth it.  In any case it is all done with one vector and no unnecessary copying.  If the condition is relatively more expensive, then using indexes instead of iterators wins, with excess copying only in case the vector capacity must be increased at a less efficient moment.